# DROP all for port 22 if not geoip set of US for iptables and xtables

Tags: ssh, iptables

I want to simply block all ssh access from anywhere but with in the US.  This is my whole iptables, and I have followed http://www.howtoforge.com/xtables-addons-on-centos-6-and-iptables-geoip-filtering

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Jul  3 02:30:42 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1749:280570]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
-A INPUT -m geoip --src-cc US --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000:3050 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul  3 02:30:42 2013
```

I have `-A INPUT -m geoip --src-cc US --dport 22 -j ACCEPT` and the goal is to only accept ssh from the us where admins work from.  as of right now I get an error.

```
iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.4.7: Couldn't load match `geoip':/lib64/xtables/libipt_geoip.so:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Error occurred at line: 10
```

***update***
I have searched for the file and can't find it any were.  Ran through the how to and realized that the Xtables-addons was version 1.37, so I updated it 2.5 but there was no change.  I look in `/lib64/xtables/` and there are tons of files but not the geoip one.  So I think that is where I need to start on how to correct the Xtables-addon install I guess.

Comment: "as of right now I get an error". And what is that error?

Comment: your right, I added the error

Comment: Did you set up the datafile stuff at `/usr/share/xt_geoip/`? Sounds like that's what it's missing.

Comment: @Patrick yes it has the `BE/` and `LE/` with all the files in it, `libipt_geoip.so` is just not in  `/lib64/xtables/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the the problem today, finally I've figured out. it's because of selinux, so just turn off selinux, and turn it on after system startup. It works for me, you can try it :)

#### set selinux to permissive

```
sudo vim /etc/selinux/config
```

SELINUX=permissive

#### set selinux enforcing by rc.local

```
vim /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

setenforce 1

Comment: You should clarify that the two indented lines are not to be run as commands, but are text to be entered.

Comment: Super, I'll give it a go, thanks for the update