# Reject ssh connections made from proxies

Tags: ssh, security, iptables, firewall

I was seeing [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144106/drop-all-for-port-22-if-not-geoip-set-of-us-for-iptables-and-xtables) question which was concerned with blocking access to the users who do not belong to a particular region. I am sure that blocking is possible but I see there is a workaround to this.

1. I login to the region's proxy from [here](http://www.freeproxy.ca/Comments~6543.html).
2. I give [this](http://www.serfish.com/console/) URL as the site to visit.
3. Now, I am in the region's proxy and I am able to login to the server
   as well.

Is there a way to reject such circumvented attempts in the `iptables`? I see this as a pretty dangerous security concern.

Comment: What's the point of the step 1 proxy? If you're using site 2 for SSH, the IP of site 2 is what the server is going to see.

Comment: @Patrick, step1 will make me login from US based IP address. I mean, the `ssh` connection will be made from an IP address that belongs to the US region. If I try to do `ssh` from some other region (apart from US), as per the question, the OP wants to reject the `ssh` connection. To overcome that, I use step1.

Comment: It won't. The SSH connection will be made from the servers of serfish.com, wherever they're located.

Comment: It isn't. You don't want to expose ssh to the external network and want to use an internal, managing network instead  with only admins having access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question looks very confused, but I think the confusion is part of the question, so I'll try to provide enough background to clarify things.

[HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) and [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) are different protocols. HTTP is spoken by HTTP clients (called web browsers) and HTTP servers (called web servers). SSH is spoken by SSH clients and SSH servers. The HTTP protocol has a notion of proxy, where a network node receives an HTTP requests from a client and forwards it to a server, and forwards the response back from the server to the client. SSH doesn't have proxies in the technical sense; however a machine that allows people who aren't using it physically to use an SSH client on it is acting as a proxy in the general English sense of the term.

http://www.freeproxy.ca/ lists HTTP proxies. They aren't useful to make SSH connections.

http://www.serfish.com/console/ is a machine that runs an SSH client which is driven from a publicly accessible web interface. If you use a web browser to connect to serfish, and run the SSH client there, then as far as the SSH server is concerned, your connection comes from serfish, full stop. There is no way for the SSH server to know that the SSH client is being driven by someone who isn't physically located in the datacenter where serfish is hosted. Note that it doesn't matter whether you're accessing serfish directly over HTTP or via an HTTP proxy; the SSH server has no way to know anything about that.

In general, a server can only know about the last hop used to connect to it. Is this a security concern? Yes, but hardly a dangerous one. Filtering connections by geographical origin cannot be done reliable; any moderately competent system administrator knows that. Geographical origin can give a clue as to whether a connection is suspicious, but it can't be the only factor. There are machines infected by malware and used as relays all over the world.

The security of SSH doesn't rely on geographical origin of connections. Filtering by geographical origin is done for only two purposes:

- For content distribution, to restrict what the non-technical 95% of the audience can do (setting proxies requires digging further than a majority of people are willing to do) and make things a bit more inconvenient for the technical 5% (proxies need to be paid or searched for, and reduce performance).
- As a hint that a connection to an account comes from an unusual location — but that's usually done at a finer-grained level than a country, which is too broad to provide a very useful hint. Some systems use this to decide whether to require a second authentication factor.

The flip side of not being able to track the ultimate origin of an SSH (or any) connection is that some amount of privacy is possible.

Comment: thanks for providing enough details and clearing my doubt. This actually answers my question :)

Answer (score 1):

So this can be done when using HTTP by looking for specific headers from the client such as:

```
HTTP_CLIENT_IP
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR
HTTP_FORWARDED
```

But AFAIK, similar headers and techniques don't exist for SSH.

There are [proxy blacklists](http://proxybl.org) that may be useful, but that's in no way a secure solution.

Comment: +1 for proxy black lists although it doesn't answer the question.:)

Comment: Thanks, and I think the answer is just no it can't be done.  But, I've been proven wrong before.

Comment: You are on the right track. It is impossible to reliably detect the use of a proxy. The best route is a blacklist.

Comment: @Patrick Yea it's tough. And in reality this wouldn't be a problem because you'd only have trusted people logging into your machine.  Now if someone can bypass public key auth then you've got bigger things to worry about than checking proxies.